# How to check ask.fm answer link?

Tags: php

I'm just trying to make a php script, which would show ask.fm answer and question, when we put a link. But I don't now how to easy do it, so can you help me?

How should it work:

```
$link = 'http://ask.fm/username/answer/01234567890';
$check_if_exist = true/false;
if ($check_if_exist == true) {
    $question = question;
    $answer = answer;
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense to me.

Comment: Does ask.fm have any api? That's usually the best way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check it by checking response code of said url. If response code is `200` then URL exists, else response code will be `404`.

This is +/- pseudo-code (not tested) and a I don't guarantee that it will work, however you get the idea of it.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://ask.fm/username/answer/01234567890');
curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$code = $info['http_code'];

if ($code === 200) {
    // question exists
} else {
    // question does not exist
}
```

Comment: ask.fm returns a 404 if the question/answer wasn't found, so this should work fine +1